# Looking for the hangouts custom URL scheme on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus, voip, google-hangouts

I have an iphone app that receives a phone number externally and pops up the phone dialer with a number loaded to dial. However, my alertview for the phone pop up gives the user the ability to select from Mobile Carrier, Facetime and Skype. I would like to add google hangouts to that option list but don't know how to call it properly.

I need to be able to invoke the hangouts app programmatically from my own IOS app and pass a phone number to it to dial. I know I can invoke it using the custom URL com.google.hangouts:// but I don't know how to pass a phone number to hangouts to place a phone call with voip so the app just opens and the user has to retype the number to make the call.

The complete list of parameters I can pass into the app via the custom URL scheme would be great and also if there is a callback function.﻿

Comment: You'd not only need Hangouts app but Hangout Dialer app.

Comment: ok...how do I invoke the hangouts dialer app from my iphone app and pass it the number to dial? Looking for the custom URL for the hangouts dialer app assuming it exists.

Comment: Here's Help link on making calls from iOS: https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3437917?hl=en and a note on the Dial Intent in API doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Phone

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?